# Correct way to compute AUC in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, auc

I'm calculating the area under the curve (AUC) in TensorFlow.
Here is part of my code:

```
    with tf.name_scope("output"):
        W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_filters_total, num_classes], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]), name="b")
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W)
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(b)
        self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.h_drop, W, b, name="scores")
        self.softmax_scores = tf.nn.softmax(self.scores)
        self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")

    # CalculateMean cross-entropy loss
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        self.losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.input_y,logits=self.scores)
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.losses) + l2_reg_lambda * l2_loss 

    # Accuracy
    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        correct_predictions = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")

    # AUC
    with tf.name_scope("auc"):
        self.auc = tf.metrics.auc(labels = tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1), predictions = self.predictions)`
```

`

In the above piece of code, `input_y` is a tensor with shape `(batch_size,2)` and `predictions` has the shape `(batch_size,)`.
Therefore the real values for `labels` and `predictions` variables in `tf.metrics.auc` are `[0,1,1,1,0,0,...]`.
I wonder if it's a correct way to compute AUC? 
I've tried with the following command:

`self.auc = tf.metrics.auc(labels = tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1), predictions = tf.reduce_max(self.softmax_scores,axis=1))`

But this only gives me zero numbers.

Another thing I notice is that while the `accuracy` is quite stable at the end of the training process, the `auc` computed by the first method keeps increasing. Is that correct?
Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48175067/1757224) might help.