# Tensorflow 1.4 tf.metrics.auc for AUC calculation

Tags: python, tensorflow, auc

I am trying to log **AUC** during **training time** of my model.

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc), `tf.metric.auc` needs a `label` and `predictions`, both of same shape.

But in my case of binary classification, `label` is a **one-dimensional** tensor, containing just the classes. And `prediction` is **two-dimensional** containing probability for each class of each datapoint.

How to calculate **AUC** in this case?

Comment: Haven't you tried fetching the actual predictions from the probabilities with `tf.argmax`?

Comment: As per I understand, for calculating AUC, you need to know probabilities for all the classes not just the class with max prob. Right ? In Binary Classifier, u can calculate the prob for other class but not in MultiClass.

Comment: You are correct, my bad. You probably want to fetch the probability of the "positive" class: `prob[:, 1]`

Comment: So Instead of passing just `labels`, I converted it into `tf.one_hot`, thus changing it's dimension to [batch * n_classes]. Now the probability is also [batch * n_classes]. AUC  is giving some value, but not sure whether it's correct :/

Comment: That does not sound right. Have you tried converting the two-dimensional probability tensor instead?

Comment: Converting two-dimensional probability tensor to One dimension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162838/discussion-between-random-28-and-e-net4).

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the parameters in the function [`tf.metrics.auc`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc):

> - `labels`: A Tensor whose shape matches predictions. Will be cast to `bool`.
> - `predictions`: A floating point Tensor of arbitrary shape and whose values are in the range `[0, 1]`.

This operation already assumes a binary classification. That is, each element in `labels` states whether the class is "positive" or "negative"  for a single sample. It is not a 1-hot vector, which requires a vector with as many elements as the number of exclusive classes.

Likewise, `predictions` represents the predicted binary class with some level of certainty (some people may call it a probability), and each element should also refer to one sample. It is not a softmax vector.

If the probabilities came from a neural network with a fully connected layer of 2 neurons and a softmax activation at the head of the network, consider replacing that with a single neuron and a sigmoid activation. The output can now be fed to `tf.metrics.auc` directly.

Otherwise, you can just slice the predictions tensor to only consider the positive class, which will represent the binary class just the same:

```
auc_value, auc_op = tf.metrics.auc(labels, predictions[:, 1])
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to always pass the probability of `Class==1`, irrespective of labels ?

Comment: @random_28 As we are dealing with binary classification, the probability of `p(Class = 0)` should be `1 - p(Class = 1)` anyway. The probability of the class being negative is not needed here.

Comment: I understand, but no where it's mentioned to pass `p(Class = 1)`. :/ How can we can confirm ? 
 As this would also work if instead we pass `p(Class= label[i])` for `i`th data point. Wot say ?

Comment: That would be because the interface already assumes that the prediction is a binary classification. The ROC curve is calculated by applying multiple thresholds over these values to construct confusion matrices. Unless you are dealing with multi-class classification, taking `p(Class = 1)` is fine. Also note that you can instead build the entire ROC curve with [`tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_curve_points`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_curve_points) and see the result for yourself.